# All Data Or None

Tags: db2, talend

I  have a simple job that reads .csv file, converts data from this file through `tMap`, and writes data from file into DB.
If an error in .csv file is found, line containing error will be escaped and all other data will be written into DB.
If die on error is checked, writing into DB will abort when line with error has been reached.

What should I do if I want that either ALL data is written into DB if there's no error, or NONE of data is written if there's at least one error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As @Ryan mentioned, the usual standard is to use a transaction.  If this isn't possible for some reason (I thought I'd heard/seen something about a row-lock limit per-transaction), consider dumping the results into a temporary copy of your actual table.  If no errors occur, add it to the production table.  If errors occur, pop an error message and drop the (temporary) table.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction). That way you can roll it back if there is an error.

Exactly how you go about implementing a transaction depends on the database you're using. Which is it?

Comment: If transaction is only solution, then I must give up. Is there any way that tMap component asserts that line is typeof Integer, or typeof String? I've tried this before writting into DB, but seems like I couldn't manage.

Comment: I don't have much experience working with DB2 specifically, but my understanding is that its transactions are implicit; you just need to tell it to do a rollback whenever there is an error, instead of committing.

Comment: A transaction is not the only way to implement this functionality, but it is the standard (and most reliable) one. Is there some reason you cannot use transactions for this?

Comment: OK, if I go with transaction, please tell me what component in TalenD should I use? I tried with existing ones from palette, but seems like can't accomplish. I would appreciate any tutorial.